# How to use javascript in iphone or ipad project to control the website?

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, ipad

Now I want to submit the username and password login a website on iphone or ipad ,so I want to need the manner of  use javascript in iphone or ipad project to control the website??

So the question is how to use javascript in iphone or ipad platform??

Answer (score 0):

MobileSafari supports JavaScript.

And UIWebView supports JavaScript.